# Android Studio not recognizes Espresso imports

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am trying to write a test case using Espresso.

I am using Android Studio 1.5.1 (Stable channel), Gradle plugin 1.5, Gradle 2.7.
The problem is that Android Studio doesn't recognize any import related to Espresso (and not only)[image]

So, I tried to clean the project, rebuild, invalidate cache and restart, but nothing.

I added these dependencies in my app module:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
```

I added the runner in defaultConfig:

```
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

I created the test suite class under androidTest folder:

[image]

What am I doing wrong please?

**UPDATE**

Here is (part) of my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 5
        versionName '1.4'

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    buildTypes {
        //my build type configs
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        preDexLibraries = false
        jumboMode = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1'
    compile project(':libraries:RITracking')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.9.0'
    compile 'com.cocosw:bottomsheet:1.2.0@aar'                          //Bottom Sheet that implement material design used for ShareDialog
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'                     //Glide library
    compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.2.3'        //Library used to parse/merge phones number to E164 format
    compile 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.3@aar'                        //Used to show badge on application icon, library is optimized to work on most of devices
    compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:1.0.3'                              //Stripe payment gateway, used to integrate credit card payment
    provided 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.6'
    apt "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.6"
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    apt "com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1"
    compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao:2.1.0'                              //Green Dao library is ORM implementation for Android SQL lite
    compile files('libs/libammsdk.jar')
    compile files('libs/apptimize-android-2.9.1.jar')

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestCompile "com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1"
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.1'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps your Build Variant is on "release" mode. you have to change it to debug.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE 30/11/2016**

Just like  @Jaymes Bearden said in comment below.

Use testBuildType. Android Studio 2.2, gradle 2.2.2

```
android {
        testBuildType "yourBuildType"
}
```

---

**OLD ANSWER**

I found not solution but some source of problem. In my project I have, a lot of BuildTypes. Especially more than one debug build.

Everything works only in default **debug** build type. I think that this is some internal Android Studio error.

My AS version - 2.1

Comment: This was exactly my issue too. I had a lot of build variants and I had the wrong one selected. I found an option though, you can use the "testBuildType" option in your app's gradle.build under the android key. Set it to whatever variant you want.

Comment: @Artur what is this  testBuildType "yourBuildType" where i have to change

Comment: You change it to whichever build you want to be testable that's listed under 'buildTypes'

Answer (score 3):

You need to use debug build variant. With other build options espresso will not be recongnised.

Comment: Or declare explicitly which buildTypes you want debuggable with 'testBuildType' as stated by @Artur Latoszewski answer

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure, that you're something missing in your configuration. compare your `build.gradle` with mine below

```
def ASVersion = '23.1.1'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.piotr.awesome"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestCompile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$ASVersion"
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.1'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$ASVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$ASVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$ASVersion"

}
```

Also choose `File -> Invalidate cache/restart` and try first option.

Hope it help

Comment: Thanks piotrek but still the same problem. I have updated the question with my build.gradle. I might wanna take a look.

Comment: @DanieleVitali, is problem fixed?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not working on that project anymore. But I can successfully run Expresso tests on other projects with AS on canary channel.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio:

Open Run menu -> Edit Configurations - 
Add a new Android Tests configuration
- Choose a module
Add a specific instrumentation runner:

android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner

Also try to update the Android Support Library from SDK Manager.

Hope this helped.
You can also try this topic: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30665135/androidtestcompile-dependencies-not-recognized-in-the-imports)

Good luck!

Comment: Already tried and and it says ut cannot find AndroidJUnitRunner. Support library is updated.

Comment: Ok...Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: Not solved yet. I have updated the question with my build.gradle.

Comment: I saw your update, but I can't find this in your code:  androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3' . Can you try to add it and see what happens?

Comment: I added it but still same problems. I don't think it's a problem of missing dependency anyway. It feels more like a problem that android studio doesn't recognize the imports or something similar.

Comment: In BuildVariants are you on Android Instrumentation Tests? And also Build Type on debug.

Comment: Yes and I also tried with AS 2.0 which doesn't have the Android Instrumentation Tests anymore and nothing

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Here is how i fixed it:

1. Go the src directory of your project in finder/explorer, select the directory containing your test.
2. Rename the directory with the prefix "androidTest" followed by the name of the flavor you are trying to test.
3. Open Android Studio, Invalidate Caches and Restart.