# Android Studio : Cannot resolve symbol "Truth" (Truth library)

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso, google-truth

After coming across this gist : https://gist.github.com/chemouna/00b10369eb1d5b00401b, I noticed it was using the `Google Truth` library : https://google.github.io/truth/. So I started by following the procedure to add the library in my `build.gradle` file in Android Studio:

```
buildscript {
  repositories.mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
  testImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:0.40"
}
```

But when I wanted to add the static imports for Truth’s entry points for my assertions java class:

```
import static com.google.common.truth.Truth.assertThat;
import static com.google.common.truth.Truth.assertWithMessage;
```

I got the error that the symbol `Truth` cannot be resolved.
I tried to rebuild my project and implement the solutions stated here: [AndroidTestCompile dependencies not recognized in the imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30665135/androidtestcompile-dependencies-not-recognized-in-the-imports), mainly running the following gradle tasks:

- ./gradlew app:dependencies
- assembleAndroidTest

but the problem persists.

Any help on that?

Should I actually add these lines in my build.gradle file ? :

```
 buildscript {
  repositories.mavenLocal()
}
```

if I already have these :

```
repositories {
   mavenCentral()
   jcenter()
   google()
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> To use the Java 8 extensions, also include
> com.google.truth.extensions:truth-java8-extension:0.40.

**NOTE**

You should call **`androidTestImplementation`**

```
androidTestImplementation "com.google.truth:truth::0.40" // Latest version 1.1.3
```

Read more information about **[Truth - Fluent assertions for Java](https://truth.dev/)** .

Comment: Thank you for your help @IntelliJ Amiya. I added the compile options and the depending in my build.gradle. But when I sync I got this error : Could not find method compileOptions() for arguments [build_4gfl49u8k92u69bygafbqspv9$_run_closure3@3a4b6224] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: Should I keep both lines in the dependencies ? : `testImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:0.40'` and `testImplementation group: 'com.google.truth.extensions', name: 'truth-java8-extension', version: '0.40'`

Comment: @younes-makhtoum Restart IDE and see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796404/could-not-find-method-compile-for-arguments-gradle

Comment: @younes-makhtoum you can. no problem

Comment: The problem is still not solved. what pointed you to the fact that I might need to use the Java 8 extensions? From what I understood, it's not mandatory and only required when intending to test specific Java 8 assertions like `Optional` and `Stream`, which is not my case.

Comment: @younes-makhtoum add `androidTestImplementation "com.google.truth:truth::0.40"`

Comment: Yes! it's fixed now! Thanks a lot. Please update your core response so that I can upvote it and mark it as the right one.

Answer (score 3):

Add the appropriate dependency to your build file:

`testImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:1.0.1"`

You need the Java 8 extensions if and only if you're testing Java 8 code (Stream, Optional, etc):

`testImplementation "com.google.truth.extensions:truth-java8-extension:1.0.1"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add mavenCentral to your repositories

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
  testImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:1.1.2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JUST DON'T FORGET TO USE

> mavenCentral() instead of jcenter()

```
allprojects {
   repositories {
      google()
      mavenCentral()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As android Gradle plugin requires java 11. Please update Gradle JDK
[image]

Comment: don't forget to resync the project with Gradle file. after JDK upgrade.