# Android Studio: Cannot import libraries JUnit and Truth

Tags: java, android, android-studio, junit, google-truth

After creating class for unit tests like in [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests#java) I imported **com.google.common.truth.Truth.assertThat** and **org.junit.Test** libraries, but android studio can't pick it up and shows errors "Cannot resolve symbol "Truth"" and "Cannot resolve symbol "Test"".

After searching the ways to solve this problem I came across a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50448004/android-studio-cannot-resolve-symbol-truth-truth-library) on StackOverflow that asked similar thing. I did all the things that were recommended over there but I still can't import those classes.

My project build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

My project module build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:1.1.3'
}
```

My test class

```
import com.google.common.truth.Truth.assertThat;
import org.junit.Test;
```

Comment: What folder are your tests in? `test` or `androidTest`? (They should be in `test`)

Answer (score 1):

Android gradle plugin requires java 11 to run.

Please change gradle java plugin to 11 like below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to resync the project with Gradle file. after Gradle JDK update